# Drag and Drop multimedia objects in IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to get the drag and drop functionality to work between browsers or between windows using HTML5 native DnD API. When setting the data type to 'text' in IE, it works, but if I embed a video and try to drag between browser, the data doesn't get replaced, but it moves to the next block in the list. Is there a way to fix this problem in both IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, so you need to use `.getData()` and then use `.innerHTML` to set it as an element.